# Far away rocket smoke simulation

Tags: animation, cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation, fire

I am making an animation where a drone in the distance fires a rocket and the rocket's path goes towards the camera.  I have a large domain for the smoke sim.  I have a small ball at the back of the rocket that is the child of the rocket where it is the inflow for smoke.  The problem I have is, the smoke simulation is so large, I mean that there is so much smoke that it drowns out the rocket and fills up the scene.  How do I create a realistic smoke/fire simulation for that?  How do I make the amount of smoke smaller to where it is proportional with the rocket? Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks,

[image]

Comment: a .blend file would help. So we see what you tried so far and what you can improve.

Comment: How do I upload that?

Comment: read and follow instructions here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/